# Measurability of Cesàro limits

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be real random variables. Then the Cesáro limit

$\displaystyle\lim\inf_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

is tail sigma algebra measurable. In order to show this, choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and note that

$\displaystyle \lim\inf_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\lim\inf_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=N}^n X_i$

is $\sigma((X_n)_{n\ge N})$ measurable.

I don't understand why I can shift the index $i$ to $N$ in the summation.

We have $\displaystyle \lim\inf_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\inf_{k\ge n}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$

and I also understand, that we can shift $k$ to an abitrary starting point, because the infimum series is increasing. But why can we shift the $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two sequences of real numbers $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are such that $b_n-a_n\to 0$, then $\liminf_{n\to +\infty}a_n=\liminf_{n\to +\infty}b_n$.

Use this with $a_n=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $b_n=n^{-1}\sum_{i=N}^nX_i$.

Comment: I suppose the same is then true for the $\lim\sup_{n\to \infty}$?

Comment: Yes it is also true.